# A particular implication of convergence in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $X$ are random variables on a probability space $(X,\Sigma,\mathbb P)$ and $X_n\overset{\mathbb P}{\to}X$. That is, for each $\varepsilon>0$, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb P\left(|X_n-X|>\varepsilon\right)=0.$$ Suppose further that the distribution of $X$ has no point mass at some $x\in\mathbb R$, that is, $\mathbb P(X=x)=0$. I want to show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb P\left(X>x\text{ and }X_n\leq x\right)=0.$$ This result would hold if $X>x$ were replaced by $X>x+\varepsilon$ ($\varepsilon>0$), but going to the limit (as $\varepsilon\downarrow0$) seems to require a trick that eludes me. Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. The assumption $\mathbb P(X=x)$ is not even needed. Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Since $$\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\left\{x<X\leq x+\frac{1}{k}\right\}=\varnothing$$ and the intersection is nested, there exists, by the continuity of probability measures from above, some $k\in\mathbb N$ such that $$\mathbb P\left(x<X\leq x+\frac{1}{k}\right)<\varepsilon.$$ Then,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P\left(X> x\text{ and }X_n\leq x\right)=&\,\mathbb P\left(X> x+\frac{1}{k}\text{ and }X_n\leq x\right)+\mathbb P\left(x<X\leq x+\frac{1}{k}\text{ and }X_n\leq x\right)\\
<&\,\mathbb P\left(|X_n-X|>\frac{1}{k}\right)+\varepsilon.
\end{align*}
Therefore, $$0\leq\limsup_{n\to\infty}\mathbb P\left(X> x\text{ and }X_n\leq x\right)\leq\varepsilon.$$